# PySpark on Databricks: Reading a CSV file copied from the Azure Blob Storage results in java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, spark-csv, azure-databricks

I am running Azure Databricks 4.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.3.1, Scala 2.11).

I copied a `CSV` file from Azure Blob Storage into Databricks cluster using `dbutils.fs.cp` into disk by adding `file:` to the absolute `local_path`:

```
copy_to = "file:" + local_path
dbutils.fs.cp(blob_storage_path, copy_to)
```

When I then try to read the file using the same path with `file:` added in front:

```
csv_spark_df = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(copy_to)
```

I am getting an error message denoting that the given path does not exist:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/<local_path>
```

When I mount the Azure Blob Storage container, as described below, then I can read the file correctly with Spark using the same snippet above, using the absolute `local_path` of the file in the mounted directory:

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-with-dbfs

Is it at all possible to read the `CSV` file that was copied from the Azure Blob Storage or is the solution using mounting of the Azure Blob Storage container the preferred one anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what the file: will map to.

I would have expected the path to be a DBFS path:

```
copy_to = "/path/file.csv"
```

This will be assumed to a DBFS path.

You can always do:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/path")
```

To verify the file copy.

Though please note you do not need to copy the file to DBFS to load into a dataframe - you can read directly from the blob storage account. That would be the normal approach. Is there a reason you want to copy it locally?

Comment: I am also working with binary files and those I had to copy to Databricks before I could parse them. For CSV files I would assume that would not be the preferred way, but I was curious why it is not working. Could it be because I added `file:` in my copy_to path?

Comment: I believe so. If you just start from root like my example I suspect it will be fine.